# com.futronic.SDKHelper cannot be resolved

Tags: java, compiler-errors, desktop-application, biometrics

i received a challenge on my job, that consists in develope a desktop system using java for collect biometrics data.
I decided to compile the java example they have on its own drive, but I'm not able to compile it due to it not recognizing the futronic drivers[Error below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBwhx.png)

I tried compiling, changing the path and it still didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you get error `xxxxx cannot be resolved` it means that your environment does not have all needed dependencies. Java ( specificcaly, the JDK ) get out with a series of classes embedded, the 'base', with you can do a lot of stuff (use file, manipulate strings, use timestamps, read user input, and so on).

If you want to do more or other stuff, you need third party library ( 1 or more .jar file) that contains what you want (in your case, SDKHelper). What you have to do is read your biometrics data provider documentation, find where to get .jar library, download it and add to your environment (classpath) to be able to use it

Comment: you are welcome, if its help you, please consider to mark answer as the right one !